# Java library AmazonS3Client.getObject never returns

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I'm experiencing an issue in which it would appear that calls to `AmazonS3Client.getObject` never returns; this is happening to us every day, and I believe it's when S3 is running it's daily expiry job.

There doesn't seem to be a way to specify a timeout value for this request, and it's causing our thread pool to become blocked indefinitely, making our entire instance unresponsive when enough of them hang indefinitely.

Is there a way to overcome? I've gone down the `Thread.interrupt` path, but am not sure if it will that signal will abided.

Here is the stack trace for where it is getting stuck:

```
"image-s3-dispatcher-10187" - Thread t@10481
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
  - parking to wait for <7945c7e6> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkUntil(LockSupport.java:267)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitUntil(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2130)
  at org.apache.http.pool.PoolEntryFuture.await(PoolEntryFuture.java:129)
  at org.apache.http.pool.AbstractConnPool.getPoolEntryBlocking(AbstractConnPool.java:281)
  at org.apache.http.pool.AbstractConnPool.access$000(AbstractConnPool.java:62)
  at org.apache.http.pool.AbstractConnPool$2.getPoolEntry(AbstractConnPool.java:176)
  at org.apache.http.pool.AbstractConnPool$2.getPoolEntry(AbstractConnPool.java:172)
  at org.apache.http.pool.PoolEntryFuture.get(PoolEntryFuture.java:100)
  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager.leaseConnection(PoolingClientConnectionManager.java:212)
  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager$1.getConnection(PoolingClientConnectionManager.java:199)
  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor22.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
  at com.amazonaws.http.conn.ClientConnectionRequestFactory$Handler.invoke(ClientConnectionRequestFactory.java:70)
  at com.amazonaws.http.conn.$Proxy9.getConnection(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:456)
  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:384)
  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:232)
  at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3528)
  at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1111)
  at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObject(AmazonS3Client.java:984)
  at com.spingo.s3client.S3Client$$anonfun$read$1.apply(S3Client.scala:110)
```

All of the 8 pending requests on which it is stuck are for files <=10kb, some of the requests are as old as 15 minutes.

Comment: You can set timeouts etc. via [ClientConfiguration](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/ClientConfiguration.html) and use it in appropriate constructor for AmazonS3Client. Also, I doubt that S3 would be so lousy to be unresponsive when the expiry job is running (considering their SLA) - there could be something going on with your network as well.

Comment: It happens at the same time every day; I've been sorting through a heap dump. I have 8 pending (my thread pool maximum) S3 requests whose metrics all have a start time, but no end time. The start times are about 5 minutes apart; the service gets about 20-30 requests per second (it's behind a CDN, which absorbs the brunt of the load), and it runs 3 instances, so maybe about 3000 requests were required to get 8 infinite-blockers in the queue.

I'll look more at ClientConfiguration.

Comment: I've looked at the ClientConfiguration; all of the default arguments (which are being used) seem sufficient to time out threads and prevent the condition I am observing.

Comment: Hi Tim, are there any news on this issue? I'm occasionally facing the same issue. At random time getObject hangs. Did you resolved the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing the following:

- Upgrade to the latest `aws-java-sdk` (1.9.7) (from 1.9.6)
- Explicitly closing the stream returned by `S3Object#getObjectContent`
- Disabled the expiry rules on amazon.

... the problem, for the first time in a week, has stopped manifesting. Difficult to tell which, if any, of those things caused the improvement.

If it were due to not explicitly closing the streams, well, I've been using the aws-java-sdk that year for several months without any issue. And, it's odd how the problem manifested for all instances at the exact time each day.

If it's disabling the expiry rules on Amazon, well, I'll report what happens when I turn them back on.

If it's upgrading the latest `aws-java-sdk`, there was no mention of the observed infinite-block issue being addressed in the release notes.

While I'm eager to understand what was really the problem, I'm not eager enough that I am going to go out of my way to try and break it again. It's something that can only be reproduced at a specific time each day. :/

--

**UPDATE**

The issue actually wasn't fixed; it just happened to not occur one day. This morning it occurred again, at a different time.

Had more luck on the AWS forums. Seems as if it all traces back to an issue with the apache http library. Leaving bread-crumbs to benefit my fellow netizens:

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=585774&#585774

--

**UPDATE 2**

Updating the apache http library didn't help. Nor did rolling back the AWS client.

There was an area in which we were checking for the existence of an object. To do so, we were calling `AmazonS3Client#getObject` and checking for an exception, thinking that `S3Object#getObjectContent` was the thing that actually fetched the stream. Reading the docs lead me to believe that. However, when reading the source code, I came to realize that getObjectContent is a simple getter and the library eager-allocates the stream. Since we didn't realize this fact, we didn't bother to call close on the stream if we didn't call `S3Object#getObjectContent`.

So, moral of the story: any time you call `AmazonS3Client#getObject`, close the stream.